# can we send sms through emulator in android?

Tags: android

i want to check the sms sending through th e emulator to phone can we do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know if is it possible to send sms from emulator to device, but it is possible to send sms from one emulator instance to another. Use emulator port number as receiver phone number, i.e. if emulator runs on port 5444 you have to use 5444 as phone number to send an sms or call from another emulator instance.

Answer (score 4):

The emulator is not connected to any cellular network so sending a real sms is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can send sms from one emulator to another one.For that you need to run two emulators .
 Use emulator port number as receiver phone number.And the emulator should have the same instance .
Like if your app is running on emulator name Em-5554 , the second emulator should be
Em-5556

Answer (score 0):

Sending SMS from 1 emulator to another with help of Device Control is possible....
But you cant send the SMS from emulator to a device (with or without connectivity) :)