# Is there a way that I can simulate an outgoing sms in an Android Emulator?

Tags: android

Does anyone know of a way to simulate an outgoing sms in an android emulator?

Comment: just use two emulator's for simulate incoming or outgoing sms

Comment: Releated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581730/can-we-send-sms-through-emulator-in-android?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes it will be possible by using opening two emulators at same time.

For suppose if your emulator numbers are 5554 and 5556.

```
btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
  {
     public void onClick(View v)
     {
         sendSMS("5556", "Hi You got a message!");                     
      }
  });

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{
   SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
   sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
}
```