# How i can Detect type of language in a string?

Tags: android

I have a SMS counter that count typed character;

I wanna when user type `English` char(English chars + sings + numbers) ,counting Variable do ++ to `Number: 160`,

But , if in all there r a `Persian` char , counting Variable do ++ to `Number: 70`

what I should to do?

**I Fined that this code : `var ucs2 = text.search(/[^\x00-\x7D]/)` in `php` return What character user ; Persian char or English.**

**The equivalent code in Java - What is Android؟**

> 

```
 private final TextWatcher TextWatcher_Method = new TextWatcher() 
  { 
     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
        {
            cnt2=matn_counter.length();

            TextView counter=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_counter);  

            cnt1=(int) Math.ceil(cnt2/6);
            Integer cnt3=(cnt2%6);

            counter.setText(Integer.toString(cnt1)+"/"+Integer.toString(cnt3));

        }
  }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581730/can-we-send-sms-through-emulator-in-android

Comment: send sms without simcard ?

Comment: salam arash - shoma link ertebati ya Id darid? - vase soal hayi ke pish miad va komak azaton bekham

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Bidi](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Bidi.html) class.
for more info look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18008575/513413) please.

Answer (score 2):

You can't send 'real' SMS from emulator to device, because you don't have a SIM card.

You can, however, send it from emulator to emulator if you have more than one running.

To do this, check this question: [Sending and receiving text using android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325669/sending-and-receiving-text-using-android-emulator)

Comment: What is the solution if i wanna send sms to a real device - i can't just whit a modem?

Comment: @saeid You can't send SMS to real device if you don't have SIM card. No SIM card = No cellular network = No SMS.

Comment: even with a GSM Modem that have sim card!? :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's some useful tips on how to send SMS, make call, etc... http://www.apurbadebnath.com/blog/android-emulator-tips/

Comment: thanx - i saw this page - but Got nowhere! i have problem too!

Comment: Try this, open 2 emulators. Send a message from one to the other using the number that appears in the emulator's title-bar. E.g. The 1st would have the number 5554 and the 2nd would have 5556, try to send from the 1st to 5556

Comment: i know it - but, i wana send real sms to a real Cell Phone

Comment: There is a free android app "Terminal IDE" available on Google Play. Install it. This app has inbuilt terminal, open the terminal and type telnetd, it will start telnet service on the android phone. Connect the phone to pc using usb. In command prompt type
    
1. adb forward tcp:[your port number] tcp:8080
2. telnet 127.0.0.1:[your port number]

Check the below links:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605678/android-how-to-telnet-a-phone
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCommandLine/article.html#emulator_console

Answer (score 0):

**The Answer:**

Actually you should check ASCII chars.

If any char is **out of ASCII** range ([0x0000 to 0x007F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_(Unicode_block))) the message becomes to **70 length limit**.

And otherwise as you motioned, if all chars is ASCII (for example English letters or numbers) the limitation on message length is 160.

the code is simple:

```
public static boolean isASCIIMessage(String s) {
for (int i = 0; i < Character.codePointCount(s, 0, s.length()); i++) {
    int c = s.codePointAt(i);
    if (c >= 0x0000 && c <=0x007F)
        return false;
}
return true;
```

Anyway if you want detect Persian input see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34740588/4983201).